# Creating a list of Times using python for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create a list of times in the format 00:00 to 23:45. I think this can be done using a for loop, but I am unsure of how to do it. I don't care about the type of the values in the list as long as the correct format of 00:00 is used. Right now I just instantiate the list with the set values, code shown below. Thank you for your help!

'''python

```
times = ['00:00', '00:15' , '00:30' , '00:45' , 
        '01:00', '01:15' , '01:30' , '01:45' , 
        '02:00', '02:15' , '02:30' , '02:45' , 
        '03:00', '03:15' , '03:30' , '03:45' , 
        '04:00', '04:15' , '04:30' , '04:45' , 
        '05:00', '05:15' , '05:30' , '05:45' , 
        '06:00', '06:15' , '06:30' , '06:45' , 
        '07:00', '07:15' , '07:30' , '07:45' , 
        '08:00', '08:15' , '08:30' , '08:45' , 
        '09:00', '09:15' , '09:30' , '09:45' , 
        '10:00', '10:15' , '10:30' , '10:45' , 
        '11:00', '11:15' , '11:30' , '11:45' , 
        '12:00', '12:15' , '12:30' , '12:45' , 
        '13:00', '13:15' , '13:30' , '13:45' , 
        '14:00', '14:15' , '14:30' , '14:45' , 
        '15:00', '15:15' , '15:30' , '15:45' , 
        '16:00', '16:15' , '16:30' , '16:45' , 
        '17:00', '17:15' , '17:30' , '17:45' , 
        '18:00', '18:15' , '18:30' , '18:45' , 
        '19:00', '19:15' , '19:30' , '19:45' , 
        '20:00', '20:15' , '20:30' , '20:45' , 
        '21:00', '21:15' , '21:30' , '21:45' , 
        '22:00', '22:15' , '22:30' , '22:45' , 
        '23:00', '23:15' , '23:30' , '23:45' ]
```

'''

Comment: Can you show an example of the code you have tried? It is ok if it doesn't work, but attempting to write the code and sharing what you have done will be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to do what you want:

```
def time_interval(hour, minute, interval):
    return [
        f"{str(i).zfill(2)}:{str(j).zfill(2)}" 
        for i in range(hour)
        for j in range(minute)
        if j % interval == 0
    ]


times = time_interval(24, 60, 15)
print(times)
```

Output:

```
['00:00', '00:15', '00:30', '00:45', '01:00', '01:15', '01:30', '01:45', '02:00', '02:15', '02:30', '02:45', '03:00', '03:15', '03:30', '03:45', '04:00', '04:15', '04:30', '04:45', '05:00', '05:15', '05:30', '05:45', '06:00', '06:15', '06:30', '06:45', '07:00', '07:15', '07:30', '07:45', '08:00', '08:15', '08:30', '08:45', '09:00', '09:15', '09:30', '09:45', '10:00', '10:15', '10:30', '10:45', '11:00', '11:15', '11:30', '11:45', '12:00', '12:15', '12:30', '12:45', '13:00', '13:15', '13:30', '13:45', '14:00', '14:15', '14:30', '14:45', '15:00', '15:15', '15:30', '15:45', '16:00', '16:15', '16:30', '16:45', '17:00', '17:15', '17:30', '17:45', '18:00', '18:15', '18:30', '18:45', '19:00', '19:15', '19:30', '19:45', '20:00', '20:15', '20:30', '20:45', '21:00', '21:15', '21:30', '21:45', '22:00', '22:15', '22:30', '22:45', '23:00', '23:15', '23:30', '23:45']
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it with just pure for loops:

```
times = []
for hour in range(24):
    for minute in range(0, 60, 15):
        times.append('{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hour, minute))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `datetime` object from the datetime package, and then use `strftime('%H:%M')` to convert this to a string:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone

[datetime.fromtimestamp(d, tz=timezone.utc).strftime('%H:%M') for d in range(0, 60*60*24, 15*60)]
```

THis gives us:

```
>>> [datetime.fromtimestamp(d, tz=timezone.utc).strftime('%H:%M') for d in range(0, 60*60*24, 15*60)]
['00:00', '00:15', '00:30', '00:45', '01:00', '01:15', '01:30', '01:45', '02:00', '02:15', '02:30', '02:45', '03:00', '03:15', '03:30', '03:45', '04:00', '04:15', '04:30', '04:45', '05:00', '05:15', '05:30', '05:45', '06:00', '06:15', '06:30', '06:45', '07:00', '07:15', '07:30', '07:45', '08:00', '08:15', '08:30', '08:45', '09:00', '09:15', '09:30', '09:45', '10:00', '10:15', '10:30', '10:45', '11:00', '11:15', '11:30', '11:45', '12:00', '12:15', '12:30', '12:45', '13:00', '13:15', '13:30', '13:45', '14:00', '14:15', '14:30', '14:45', '15:00', '15:15', '15:30', '15:45', '16:00', '16:15', '16:30', '16:45', '17:00', '17:15', '17:30', '17:45', '18:00', '18:15', '18:30', '18:45', '19:00', '19:15', '19:30', '19:45', '20:00', '20:15', '20:30', '20:45', '21:00', '21:15', '21:30', '21:45', '22:00', '22:15', '22:30', '22:45', '23:00', '23:15', '23:30', '23:45']
```